# Shutdown Equivalent of ApplicationContextInitializer

Tags: java, spring, apache-zookeeper, apache-curator

How can I cleanly shut down resources used in an `ApplicationContextInitializer` implementation?

I've created an `ApplicationContextInitializer` implementation that uses the Curator project to connect to Zookeeper and acquire a properties file. It then creates a `Properties` instance , a `PropertiesPropertySource` and adds that to the context.

When the application shuts down, I'd like to be able to call `close()` on the `CuratorFramework` instance that was a member of my initializer. How is this best done?

Could I also pass the `CuratorFramework` instance *into* the context, so I can use it as a bean?

Answer (score 6):

In your `ApplicationContextInitializer`, you can add an `ApplicationListener<ContextClosedEvent>`:

```
class MyContextInitializer implements ApplicationContextInitializer<ConfigurableApplicationContext> {
        @Override
        public void initialize(ConfigurableApplicationContext applicationContext) {

            applicationContext.addApplicationListener(new ApplicationListener<ContextClosedEvent>() {
                @Override
                public void onApplicationEvent(ContextClosedEvent event) {
                    /* Cleanup code */
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I would create a bean that gets the spring events, and use that to close curator,

```
public class CuratorDisposer implements DisposableBean { 
    private CuratorFramework delegate; //set through spring somehow

    public void destroy() {
          delegate.close();
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> When the application shuts down, I'd like to be able to call close()
>   on the CuratorFramework instance that was a member of my initializer.
>   How is this best done?

You could have your initializer class implement `ApplicationListener`, and then register itself as a listener on the context.  You would then receive the `ContextClosedEvent` when the context shuts down.

> Could I also pass the `CuratorFramework` instance *into* the context, so I can use it as a bean?

You could possibly do something like this in your initializer (not tested):

```
RootBeanDefinition cfDef = new RootBeanDefinition(MethodInvokingFactoryBean.class);
cfDef.getPropertyValues().add("targetClass", MyInitializer.class);
cfDef.getPropertyValues().add("targetObject", this);
cfDef.getPropertyValues().add("targetMethod", "getCuratorFramework");
((BeanDefinitionRegistry)ctx).registerBeanDefinition("curatorFramework", cfDef);
```

and add a `getCuratorFramework()` method to your initializer class, returning the `CuratorFramework` you created at init time.